# could not pass the “Id” to the controller's parameter in the popup system

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to delete data from DB.but I am facing a problem. when I click the delete button I saw the unexpected result. I think this controller parameter can not found the parameter value. but I passed the value from View perfectly.

Here is my code:

passing data from view to the controller(Index.cshtml)(Please focus 2nd button "Delete")

```
@model IEnumerable<Practise.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-model" data-target="#addEmployee" data-url="@Url.Action("Create")">Create</button>
</br></br>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @*<partial name="_ButtonPartial" model="@item.Id" />*@
                    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-model" data-target="#addEmployee" data-url="@Url.Action($"Delete/{item.Id}")">Delete</button>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var save = '@TempData["save"]'

            if (save!= null) {
                alertify.success(save);
            }

        })

    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var category = _db.Category.Find(id);
    return View(category);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delete (Category scategory)   //input parameter
{
    _db.Category.Remove(scategory);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Delete.cshtml

```
@model Practise.Models.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<div class="modal fade" id="#addEmployee">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="#addEmployeeLabel">Add Category</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>x</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-action="Delete" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CategoryName"> </label>
                        <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control" />
                        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>*@
                        <h1 class="text-danger">Are You Delete This Product?</h1>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS(site.js)

```
$(function () {
    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-model"]').click(function (event) {

        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
        $.get(decodedUrl).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })
    PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {

        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form'); 
          var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
          var sendData = form.serialize();
            $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        })
    })
})
```

Here is my output, when I click the delete button:
[image]

then I found an unexpected output:
[image]

but I want to delete this using the popup system. for that must work of my delete view as a popup.  what's wrong here I didn't understand.
I am a beginner please help.

Comment: did you check what does `data` has in it ? When you do this - >`PlaceHolderElement.html(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Already saw your answer about `id`. When I first to saw your codes, I thought you need pop dialog about Delete , so I see some errors in you `View` and updated for u.

```
@model IEnumerable<Practise.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

    <div id="PlaceHolderHere">


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-model" data-target="#addEmployee" data-url="@Url.Action("Create")">Create</button>
        </br></br>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    var tm = "#myModal" + item.Id;
                    var mid = "myModal" + item.Id;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*<partial name="_ButtonPartial" model="@item.Id" />*@
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=@tm>Delete</button>

                            <div class="modal fade" id=@mid tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="#addEmployeeLabel">Delete Category</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <span>x</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">


                                            @{ var Id = @item.Id;}
                                            <form asp-action="Delete">

                                                CategoryName : @item.CategoryName
                                                Id: <input asp-for="@Id" />
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <h1 class="text-danger">Are You Delete This Product?</h1>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Delete</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>


                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>


@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var save = '@TempData["save"]'

            if (save != null) {
                alertify.success(save);
            }

        });

    </script>


    <script>
        $(function () {

            var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');

            $('button[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function (event) {

                var url = $(this).data('url');
                var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
                $.get(decodedUrl).done(function (data) {
                    PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
                    PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
                });
            });

            $('button[data-save="modal"]').click(function (event) {

                var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
                var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
                var sendData = form.serialize();
                $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {

                    PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                });

            });

        });


    </script>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here my problem was, I did not properly pass "id".just change this, and it will perfectly work.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-model" data-target="#addEmployee" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Id })">Delete</button>
```